# remove a tab e at the end of a line

Tags: text-processing

```
printf "%s\t" HEMES n{1..1600} >file_a
sed -i 's/\t*$//' file_a > file_a
```

removes a tab which is caused at the end of the line after the first line of the code (where the stuff is printed) .

My problem is now that i would need to remove the tab behind that line (starting with HEMES) in a larger file which has more lines. If I just try the sed line that does not work. The line I want to remove the character from is always the first line of the file .

Comment: `sed -i 's/\t*$//' file_a > file_a` will wipe out your file. Did you mean `sed -i 's/\t*$//' file_a`?

Comment: What do you mean with "behind" that line? Also it's not clear what you want to do, please post an example of your current file and an example of how you'd like it to be.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing everything in one line and outputting to file, separate it in two parts - output the HEMES string and then append the n{1...1600} sequence: `printf "%s" HEMES > file_a; printf "%s\t" n{1..1600} >> file_a`.

If you specifically need to remove that tab between HEMES and n1 in an already existing file, here's an `awk` solution:

`awk ' {sub(/[[:blank:]]/,""); print}  ' file_a > tmp_file && cat tmp_file > file_a`.

What this does is take sub function, which deletes the *first* occurrence of the tab, we output that text to a temporary file, and then take those contents back to file_a. The reason for the switching between files is this: unless you are using awk version that allows inline editing (gnu awk, I believe), this will work in any case - awk, mawk, nawk, etc.

Comment: The awk master is back :)